# apply textarea scrollbar to it's outer div

Tags: html, css, textarea, scrollbar

I'm looking for a good way to achieve the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="outer">
  <textarea class="content"></textarea>
</div>
```

Really just need to get either:

- textarea to wrap after certain width or character limit
- scrollbar applied to outer div in a textarea

Trying to avoid `contenteditable` as it introduces other problems.

> Note: The solution would also need to have a fluid outer div (width fixed width on the textarea).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this on your html.

```
<div id="divScroll" class="scroll">
     <textarea class="content"></textarea>
</div>
```

On the css part.

```
.scroll {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 75%;
}

.content{
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

}

This one works fine with me.
Good luck!